# Store data of page one and use it on page 2 without using PHP GET

Tags: php, html

I have a membership site and I want to give user free trial.

In pricing page there's is an option to Choose membership plan and button "Start Free Trial".

Clicking the Free Trial will redirect to register.

Later on, I want the Membership Plan I pick to be inserted on database along with the user registration. //Note that user is not yeat registered so I can insert the database after clicking free trial button so I want to store it temporarily on Registration page and use it later

How can I do that in PHP Session? Is this the standard way? Or there's a proper way to do it?

I have a custom template pricing.php and register.php and I've tried the ff code:

pricing.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['trial_data'] = 'Membership Level 2';
```

register.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['trial_data'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['trial_data']; //will insert this data alongside with the registration
}
```

Comment: You have to call `session_start()` too in `register.php`.

Comment: @KarloKokkak I've tried adding the session start on register.php but still it's not displaying.

Comment: You can store those details in a user table which is flagged trial or something. The on real subscription make the registration official by changing the flag. If the trial ends and no subscription happens then delete the user from database.

Comment: You can also just create a temporary user table. And on real subscription, move the record to the subscribed user table.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it right on your code sample, it seens theres a bug elsewhere clearing the data.

Try to use a microframework like slim 3 to help you with session management.

take a look at this simple slim 3 middleware https://github.com/bryanjhv/slim-session